# How to convert 'event' data to panel data?

Tags: r, dataframe, dataformat, long-format-data

I have data for a number of retail branches and the date at which they closed, if they didn't close then this is NA. I would like to expand these data so that they are a panel, with a 0/1 indicator to show if the branch was closed in that, or subsequent, years.

This is an example of the data format that I have and the data format that I would like. Here the data covers the period 2015 to 2019, 5 years. Branches A, B and D stay open, but branch C closes in 2016 and branch E in 2019.

```
branch <- LETTERS[1:5]
yearclosed <- c(NA, NA, 2016, NA, 2019)

have.df <- data.frame(branch, yearclosed)
have.df

branch <- c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5), rep("C",5), rep("D",5), rep("E",5))
year <- rep(2015:2019, 5)
closed <-c (rep(0,5), rep(0,5), 0,1,1,1,1, rep(0,5), 0,0,0,0,1)

want.df <- data.frame(branch, year, closed)
want.df
```

I have tried to experiment with converting from wide to long format but not made much progress. I could write a couple of for-loops, but these are generally not the best solution in R? Does anyone have any similar experiences they can share with me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code from question to generate `have.df`

```r
branch <- LETTERS[1:5]
yearclosed <- c(NA, NA, 2016, NA, 2019)
have.df <- data.frame(branch, yearclosed)
```

Load libraries

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

Prepare `have.df` by triming of missings, renaming the `yearclosed`, and
creating a new `closed` column that is `1` for every row.

```r
have.df <- 
  have.df |> 
  filter(!is.na(yearclosed)) |> 
  rename(year = yearclosed) |> 
  mutate(closed = 1)
```

Using `tidyr::expand_grid()` we can create the first two columns
of the data.frame you want and then join it with the modified `have.df` to
obtain the result you are looking for. Using `group_by()` and `fill()` we can set all years after the initial closing year to 1. `mutate()` and `coalesce()` help us to set all missing values in `closed` to `0`.

```r
expand_grid(branch = LETTERS[1:5], year = 2015:2019) |> 
  left_join(have.df) |> 
  group_by(branch) |> 
  fill(closed) |> 
  mutate(closed = coalesce(closed, 0)) |> 
  print(n = 25)
#> Joining, by = c("branch", "year")
#> # A tibble: 25 × 3
#>    branch  year closed
#>    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 A       2015      0
#>  2 A       2016      0
#>  3 A       2017      0
#>  4 A       2018      0
#>  5 A       2019      0
#>  6 B       2015      0
#>  7 B       2016      0
#>  8 B       2017      0
#>  9 B       2018      0
#> 10 B       2019      0
#> 11 C       2015      0
#> 12 C       2016      1
#> 13 C       2017      1
#> 14 C       2018      1
#> 15 C       2019      1
#> 16 D       2015      0
#> 17 D       2016      0
#> 18 D       2017      0
#> 19 D       2018      0
#> 20 D       2019      0
#> 21 E       2015      0
#> 22 E       2016      0
#> 23 E       2017      0
#> 24 E       2018      0
#> 25 E       2019      1
```

Comment: Close, but Branch C needs to be coded as closed in 2017 to 2019 as well. I will have a look at your code and see if I can make a modification to achieve what I'd like to have. Thanks.

Comment: I see. That can be accomplished with a combination of `group_by()` and `fill()`. I updated my answer.